# jQuery "selectable" with "td" filter

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

i have a question about `selectable` function in jQuery with "filter".

In demo I added some code, can you tell me why this code not work?

In this example that works very well( you can drag across the checkboxes, then check a bunch of them) : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/ZV7Xj

In this I don't want to add "class" in "td", but rather with td-width(filter) : 
http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/U6PjL/5/

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` and `cancel` options can only contain jQuery selectors, not arbitrary expressions.  You can use:

```
filter: 'td[width='+tdWidthLimit+']'
```

to create a selector that matches a specific width. But there's no selector for an attribute greater than a given value, so I don't think your `cancel` option can be done. The closest would be to match elements with a different width:

```
cancel: 'td[width!='+tdWidthLimit+']'
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/U6PjL/6/